# How to put some word in one of the columns in R if 8 another columns have text I am looking for?

Tags: r

I  have a dataframe in R. There are clients list and package of services they used by month from Jan to Aug. If one client used same service all 8 month I want to put the name of this service to the column called PU. 
For example, as you see in image, client5 used standard services all 8 month, as a result we see "standard" in PU column.

I tried code below, but it worked only for first and last month:

```
Database$PU[Database[, 2] == "Standard" & Database[, 3] == "Standard" &
Database[, 4] == "Standard" & Database[, 5] == "Standard" & 
Database[, 6] == "Standard" & Database[, 7] == "Standard" & 
Database[, 8] == "Standard" & Database[, 9] == "Standard"] <- "Standard"
```

How can I solve it? Is it possible to this without creating a new dataframe?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `apply` row-wise to assign unique value in the row to new column if it has the same value in the entire row.

```
df$PU <- apply(df[2:9], 1, function(x) if(length(unique(x)) == 1) unique(x) else '')
df

#  clients      jan      feb      mar      apr      may      jun      jul      aug       PU
#1 client1 standard standard standard standard standard standard standard standard standard
#2 client2    super    super    super standard    start    start    start    start         
#3 client3    start    start    start standard    super    start    start    start         
#4 client4    super standard    start    start    super    start    super    super         
#5 client5    super    super    super    super    super    super    super    super    super
```

---

We can use the similar approach using `dplyr` after gathering the data in longer format.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
 tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = 2:9) %>%
 group_by(clients) %>%
 summarise(PU = if(n_distinct(value) == 1) unique(value) else '') %>%
 left_join(df)
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(clients = paste0('client', 1:5), 
             jan = c('standard', 'super', 'start', 'super', 'super'), 
             feb = c('standard', 'super', 'start', 'standard', 'super'), 
             mar = c('standard', 'super', 'start', 'start', 'super'), 
             apr = c('standard', 'standard', 'standard', 'start', 'super'), 
             may = c('standard', 'start', 'super', 'super', 'super'), 
             jun = c('standard', 'start', 'start', 'start', 'super'), 
             jul = c('standard', 'start', 'start', 'super', 'super'), 
             aug = c('standard', 'start', 'start', 'super', 'super'), 
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: what is x? should I write "Standard" instead of x?

Comment: @AsemKa No, just replace `df` with `Database`. so try `Database$PU <- apply(Database[-1], 1, function(x) if(length(unique(x)) == 1) unique(x) else '')`

Comment: it doesn't work, PU column is empty now. Thank you anyway

Comment: @AsemKa Can you try `Database$PU <- apply(Database[2:9], 1, function(x) if(length(unique(x)) == 1) unique(x) else '')` ?

Comment: thank you so much!  this one works: Database$PU <- apply(Database[2:9], 1, function(x) if(length(unique(x)) == 1) unique(x) else '')